# In Scala, can I implicitly convert only certain literals to my custom type?

Tags: scala, macros, literals, implicit-conversion

In my app, I am keeping track of the number of credits the user has. To add some type checking, I'm using a `Credits` class similar to this one:

```
case class Credits(val numCredits: Int) extends Ordered[Credits] {
   ...
}
```

Suppose I have a function `def accept(creds: Credits): Unit` that I want to call. Would there be a way for me to call it with

```
process(Credits(100))
process(0)
```

but not with this?

```
process(10)
```

I.e., I'd like to provide an implicit conversion only from the literal `0` and none other. Right now, I just have `val Zero = Credits(0)` in the companion object and I think that's rather good practice, but I'd be interested in an answer anyway, including other comments, like:

- could this be done with macro implicit conversions in 2.10?
- should `Credits` rather extend AnyVal and not be a case class in 2.10?

Comment: Are you still looking for type safety?  You can, of course, `implicit`ly convert from `0` to `Credits(0)`, as I'm sure you know, but that's from `Int` to `Credits`, not from `0` to `Credits`.  In other words, you can do what you want, but not with type safety, as far as I know.

Comment: @DerekWyatt That's exactly what I want to avoid. I just want to auto convert from one literal only (`0`).

Comment: What is wrong with `object _0 extends Credits(0)` ?

Comment: @KimStebel If you want it prefix-free (i.e. not `Credits._0`, which is IMO worse than `Credits.Zero`) it will conflict with other such classes I have, where I apply the same pattern.

Comment: So just do `object Zero` and then write some implicit conversions to Credits and your other classes. But why would such "conflicts" even be bad? That's what packages are for.

Comment: @KimStebel Thanks for the workaround, which is worth mentioning, but it doesn't tell me how I could provide an implicit conversion for one literal, if I wanted to.

Comment: Helpful question. Arrived here when wondering at how the ergonomics of tagged types (_à la_ Shapeless) could be improved with implicit conversion of literals: `val x: String @@ Tag = "s"` but not symbols: `val x = "s"; val y: String @@ Tag = x`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This kind of compile-time checking are the good terrain to use macros, which will be available in 2.10

A very smart guy named *Jason Zaugg* has already implemented something similar to what you need, but it applies to regex: *Regex Compile Time checking.*

You might want to look to its Macrocosm to see how it is done and how you could code your own macros with the same purpose.

https://github.com/retronym/macrocosm

If you really want to know more about Macros, firstly I would say that you need to be brave because the documentation is scarce for now and the API is likely to change. Jason Zaugg works compiles fine with 2.10-M3 but I am not sure it will works with the newer version.

If you want to start with some readings:

- A good entry point is the scalamacros website http://scalamacros.org/ and the SIP document https://docs.google.com/document/d/1O879Iz-567FzVb8kw6N5OBpei9dnbW0ZaT7-XNSa6Cs/edit?pli=1
- If you have time, you might also wants to read Eugene Burmako presentation: 
  http://scalamacros.org/talks/2012-04-28-MetaprogrammingInScala210.pdf

Now, getting to the topic, Scala macros are **CATs** : "Compile-time AST Transformations". 
The abstract syntax tree is the way the compiler represents your source code. The compiler applies consequent transformations to the AST and at the last step it actual generates the java bytecode.

Let's now look to Jason Zaugg code:

```
 def regex(s: String): scala.util.matching.Regex = macro regexImpl

  def regexImpl(c: Context)(s: c.Expr[String]): c.Expr[scala.util.matching.Regex] = {
    import c.universe._

    s.tree match {
      case Literal(Constant(string: String)) =>
        string.r // just to check
        c.reify(s.splice.r)
    }
  }
```

As you seen regex is a special function which takes a String and returns a Regex, by calling macro regexImpl

A macro function receives a context in the first parameter lists, and in second argument list the parameters of the macro under the form of c.Expr[A]  and returns a c.Expr[B]. Please note that c.Expr is a path dependent type, i.e. it is a class defined inside the Context, so that if you have two context the following is illegal

```
val c1: context1.Expr[String] = ...
val c2: context2.Expr[String] = ...
val c3: context1.Expr[String] = context2.Expr[String] // illegal , compile error
```

Now if you look what happens in the code:

- There is a match block which matches on s.tree
- If s.tree is a Literal, containing a constant String , string.r is called

What's going on here is that there is an implicit conversion from string to StringOps defined in Predef.scala, which is automatically imported in the compilation every scala source

`implicit def augmentString(x: String): StringOps = new StringOps(x)`

StringOps extends scala.collection.immutable.StringLike, which contains:

```
def r: Regex = new Regex(toString)
```

Since macros are executed at compile time, this will be executed at compile time, and compilation will fail if an exception will be thrown (that is the behaviour of creating a regex from an invalid regex string)

---

Note: unluckily the API is very unstable, if you look at  http://scalamacros.org/documentation/reference.html you will see a broken link towards the Context.scala. The right link is  https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.10.x/src/reflect/scala/reflect/makro/Context.scala

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. If you feel like adding an example, be my guest :-)

Comment: Also the API isn't supposed to change a lot between now and 2.10.0-final. The transition between M3 and M4 was drastic, but now we're just fixing bugs.

Comment: Allrighty I've updated the reflection pdf to bring it up to speed with M5. Thanks for the nudge :)

Comment: The problem with this is, if he implements a similar solution, foo(0) will be implicitly converted while foo(1-1) won't.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you want [dependent types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type). Why Scala supports a limited form of dependent types in path dependent types, it can't do what you ask.

[Edmondo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/701829/edmondo1984) had a great idea in suggesting macros, but it has some limitations. Since it was pretty easy, I implemented it:

```
case class Credits(numCredits: Int)        
object Credits {
  implicit def toCredits(n: Int): Credits = macro toCreditsImpl

  import scala.reflect.makro.Context
  def toCreditsImpl(c: Context)(n: c.Expr[Int]): c.Expr[Credits] = {
    import c.universe._                                                                          

    n.tree match {                                                                               
      case arg @ Literal(Constant(0)) =>                                                         
        c.Expr(Apply(Select(Ident("Credits"), newTermName("apply")),           
          List(arg)))
      case _ => c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, "Expected Credits or 0")                            
    }                                                                                            
  }                                                                                              
}
```

Then I started up REPL, defined `accept`, and went through a basic demonstration:

```
scala> def accept(creds: Credits) { println(creds) }
accept: (creds: Credits)Unit

scala> accept(Credits(100))
Credits(100)

scala> accept(0)
Credits(0)

scala> accept(1)
<console>:9: error: Expected Credits or 0
              accept(1)
                     ^
```

Now, to the problem:

```
scala> val x = 0
x: Int = 0

scala> accept(x)
<console>:10: error: Expected Credits or 0
              accept(x)
                     ^
```

In other words, I can't track properties of the value assigned to identifiers, which is what dependent types would allow me to do.

But the whole strikes me as wasteful. Why do you want *just* 0 to be converted? It seems you want a default value, in which case the easiest solution is to use a default value:

```
scala> def accept(creds: Credits = Credits(0)) { println(creds) }
accept: (creds: Credits)Unit

scala> accept(Credits(100))
Credits(100)

scala> accept()
Credits(0)
```

Comment: Daniel, I would not have expected this from such an experienced developer. It only depends on your matching block where you match only against Literal of Constants of 0 and in the other cases you throw an error: you do not consider the case where the tree contains an expression evaluating to 0. Try to add an extra clause to the match

Comment: @Edmondo1984 Any expression that can be evaluated at compile time will have been evaluated already. In other words, `accept(1-1)` succeeds.

Comment: Are you sure? What type has the n.tree when you pass the int?

Comment: What you have remarkably notice is that vals are not evaluated at compile time. This in some sense reasonable because in most of the cases vals are inside classes and can be overriden or are anyways not initialized from a literal . That does not mean that you can't match a val ... Because I expect the tree of a val initialized with a constant  to be a literal constant.

Comment: @Edmondo1984 The code is there, it's pretty easy to test for yourself. In fact, there was an e-mail not long ago about someone complaining that literal expressions were evaluated before macros got a chance to look at them. And while it could be a bit smarter, it would be a lot more trouble for very little gain.

Comment: I can't very helpful because my Intellij Idea gets completely confused with the new sources and I can't explore the types... :(

Answer (score 1):

Use could use an implicit partial function:

```
scala> case class Credits(val numCredits: Int)
defined class Credits

scala> def process(c: Credits) = {}
process: (c: Credits)Unit

scala> implicit def i2c:PartialFunction[Int, Credits] = { case 0 => Credits(0) }

i2c: PartialFunction[Int,Credits]
```

Allows you

```
scala> process(Credits(12))
```

and

```
scala> process(0)
```

But:

```
scala> process(12)
scala.MatchError: 12 (of class java.lang.Integer)
        at $anonfun$i2c$1.apply(<console>:9)
        at $anonfun$i2c$1.apply(<console>:9)
        at .<init>(<console>:12)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:11)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(IMain.scala:704)

        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.IMain$Request$$anonfun$14.apply(IMain.sca
la:920)
        at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.Line$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(Line.scala:4
3)
        at scala.tools.nsc.io.package$$anon$2.run(package.scala:25)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Edit: But yes, the compiler will still allow `process(12)` resulting in a match error at runtime.

Comment: The approach would be interesting if the compiler disallowed `process(12)`, but a runtime exception instead looks pretty bad to me.